# Intel video driver upgrade now makes my external monitor display red-only with HDMI cable

Tags: windows-7, drivers, video, hdmi

I have an HP G60 notebook with a Mobile Intel 4 Series Express Chipset video display (Driver version is 8.15.10.2021). OS is Win7 Home Premium.

I also have an LG widescreen display that I was connecting to the laptop using an HDMI cable.

It was working great, until I applied an Intel 4 Series Express Chipset update from Windows Update.

After the update, if I plug the laptop to the monitor using the HDMI cable, it appears I only get the Magenta channel, cause that is all I see.

If I connect with the VGA cable, it works fine.

So, is it possible it is just the HDMI cable (which IS cheap in this case - fire sale at Blockbuster), and not related to the video driver update at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not the cable. With a serial link like HDCP, either it'll work or it won't. It doesn't sound like an HDCP issue, either. It sounds like the new driver is buggy. Roll back to the previous driver (see the relevant entry/entries in Device Manager, right-click, Properties, Roll Back Driver).

Comment: Oddly enough, it doesn't let me rollback the driver - the button is disabled.

However, Intel just released a NEW driver - might as well give that a shot.

Comment: Updating the driver might have done it - it was pink immediately after the update, but I unplugged the cable and re-plugged in it and PnP apparently sorted itself out.

Maybe the monitor device driver?